# null value for primary key when trying to insert list of dictionaries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a large number of inserts with one call, and the way someone here recommended was by giving `.insert` a list of dictionaries. This is using SQLAlchemy Core.

As an example:

```
    try:
        engine = db.create_engine(f"postgres://user:pass@myip/addressbook", connect_args={'connect_timeout': 5})
        connection = engine.connect()
        metadata = db.MetaData()
    except exc.OperationalError:
        print_error(f":: Could not connect to myip!")
        sys.exit()

    table_addressbook = db.Table('addressbook', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

    list = []
    list.append({'firstname': "John", 'lastname': "Doe"})
    list.append({'firstname': "Jane", 'lastname': "Doe"})

    query = db.insert(table_addressbook).values(list)
    connection.execute(query)
```

But I'm getting an error saying the column `id` violates a non-null constraint. This is because insert normally auto-generates the primary-key `id`. How do I use this method but specify that `id` should be auto-generated? Or is there a different method I should use?

**edit**

Table name is `addressbook`.

Column `id` is type `integer` with default `sequence` 'untitled_table_id_seq', constraints are `PRIMARY_KEY`. This was autogenerated by Postico for Mac, but I've always been able to insert without including `id` and it auto increments from the last inserted ID.

Columns `firstname` and `lastname` are type `text`, no default, no constraints.

Comment: check `address_book` table declaration and add `uuid` autogeneration for `id` column

Comment: I'm confused. It does auto-generate in any other example. Also, the details of uuid autogeneration on other posts discusses using your system's MAC address combined with other things, but the ID's I'm talking about just increment each time..

Comment: @Max, can you provide how you have created the model and the connection code also.

Answer (score 1):

Without any information on your model and/or connection it is a bit difficult to answer your question. Please find below a piece of code which uses `insert` without throwing non-null constraint errors. Hopefully it helps you.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import insert

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column(String)
    lastname = Column(String)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session.configure(bind=engine)  # once engine is available
session = Session()

new_users = []
new_users.append({'firstname': "John", 'lastname': "Doe"})
new_users.append({'firstname': "Jane", 'lastname': "Doe"})

i = insert(User).values(new_users)
session.execute(i)
```

PS: most of this is coming from the tutorial on: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using SQLAlchemy Core.. I'll post my code above now.

Comment: Ah this did end up helping me in combination with a bug I found in my code. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()

# Example Model definition for the illustration
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customer"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    description = Column(String(255))

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

######################################################
# Bulk insert using dictionaries.
######################################################
# Insert test records into `customer`table.

def bulk_insert_customers(n):
    session = Session(bind=engine)
    session.bulk_insert_mappings(
        Customer,
        [
            dict(
                name="customer name %d" % i,
                description="customer description %d" % i,
            )
            for i in range(n)
        ],
    )
    session.commit()
```

Refer these for more examples of how to do bulk inserts in different ways:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/performance/bulk_inserts.html

Comment: I'm using SQLAlchemy core, sorry, forgot to mention that before. Updated my post with full code and table information.